# ng-include in ng-table doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

In my table, I have

```
<tr
  ng-repeat="question in $data"
  ng-include="'/views/partials/questionList.html'"></tr>
```

And in `questionList.html`, I have:

```
<td class="top-td" data-title="'ID'" sortable="'id'">
  <a href="#" ng-click="loadQuestionModal(question.id)">
    {{ question.id }}
  </a>
</td>
<td class="top-td" data-title="'Question / Instruction'">
  <h6 markdown-to-html="question.Instruction.instructionText"></h6>
  <blockquote ng-show="k8englishSubject" markdown-to-html="question.questionText"></blockquote>
  <blockquote markdown-to-html="question.questionText" mathjax-bind="question.questionText" ng-show="k8mathSubject"></blockquote>
</td>
<td class="top-td"><ng-include src="'/views/partials/answerList.html'"></ng-include></td>
<td class="top-td" ng-show="k8englishSubject">
  <a ui-sref="passages.upsert({passageId: question.PassageId})" ng-show="question.PassageId">
    {{ question.Passage.passageTitle }}
  </a>
</td>
<td class="top-td" data-title="'Level'" sortable="'level'">{{ question.level }}</td>
```

However, that doesn't render any titles. If, however, I have a regular `tr` and put the `td` in the same view, then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not totally clear what's happening but both `ng-repeat` and `ng-include` create child scopes.

I would suggest you replace `ng-include` with your own directive to avoid the additional child scope

```
<tr  ng-repeat="question in $data" my-directive></tr>
```

JS

```
app.directive('myDirective',function(){
    return {
         restrict:'A',
         templateUrl:'/views/partials/questionList.html';
     };
});
```

As it stands , the only functionality of this directive is to provide the template and it will inherit parent scope of `ng-repeat` child within each iteration